# Как создать универсальный экран приложения андроид?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, экран

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_for_actionbar"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                  
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/refresh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                    android:clickable="true"

                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
                    app:tint="@color/white" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/rate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/settings"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:gravity="bottom" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mosque"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_for_text"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">




                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/location" />

                            <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/shape_for_shim"
                                app:shimmer_auto_start="false">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/locationview"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="left"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    android:text="                              "
                                    />
                            </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/timeView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#58C55D" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                               
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:gravity="left"
                            
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/shape_for_shim"
                                app:shimmer_auto_start="false"
                                android:layout_height="24dp">
                                <TextView
                                   
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="right"
                                    android:text="          "
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="18sp" />
                            </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="365dp"
                        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/white" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                               
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                app:shimmer_auto_start="false"
                                android:background="@drawable/shape_for_shim"
                                android:layout_height="24dp">
                            <TextView
                               
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="          "
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                            </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="365dp"
                        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/white" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                               
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:text="Пешин"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                app:shimmer_auto_start="false"
                                android:background="@drawable/shape_for_shim"
                                android:layout_height="24dp">
                            <TextView
                               
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="          "
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                            </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <View
                        android:layout_width="365dp"
                        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/white" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                              
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:gravity="left"
                               
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                app:shimmer_auto_start="false"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/shape_for_shim"
                                android:layout_height="24dp">
                            <TextView
                              
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="          "
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                            </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                   

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_for_bottombar"
        android:orientation="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

объясните мне, как создать экран для приложения андроид, чтобы он не менял форму и размещался во всех видах телефонов? Например моё приложение полностью размешается на моём устройстве самсунг, а на Huawei, Redmi экран не размещается, размер экранов одинаков на этих устройствах.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял формулировку:

> моё приложение полностью размешается на моём устройстве самсунг, а на
> Huawei, Redmi экран не размещается, размер экранов одинаков на этих
> устройствах.

но могу допустить что вы указали фиксированный размер виджетов и на одном из устройств у вас все помещается на экране, а где-то не помещается. Это нормально если вы указали фиксированный размер. Например если у вас кнопка имеет размер:

```
android:layout_width="500dp"
```

то понятное дело она где-то будет влезать а где-то нет. НО на примере кнопки, если вы укажете ей такую ширину:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

ширина кнопки займет весь родительский контейнер, и будет равна ширине экрана. Дальше вы уже при помощи margin можете как вам нужно уменьшить ее размер. И все будет адаптивно и красиво. Дальше вы можете посмотреть в сторону [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) и сделать адаптивную разметку, чтобы например кусок макета всегда занимал 30% экрана. Дальше вам просто нужно просмотреть ваш макет, и убрать фиксированные размеры.

P.S. к вопросу лучше прикреплять какую-то разметку или типа того, потому что без более подробного описания сложно понять что не так :(

Comment: Вот вам разметка моего приложения

Comment: вы мне предлагаете перелопатить тонну кода?) я вам предложил очевидное решение) у вас по коду часто встречается фиксированный размер, плюс насколько я знаю не рекомендуется на разметке размещать много (80+) элементов, я конечно не считал их, но все-так я бы вам советовал оптимизировать разметку немного)